# Payment gateway Inchoo doesn't show up on checkout page Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout

I'm using magento 2 , and I enabled the Inchoo Stripe payment gateway using [this](https://github.com/Inchoo/magento2-Inchoo_Stripe) , It comes out into the admin panel , I manage to add the api key , but when I go on the frontend , add a product and go to the checkout page , the payment module doesn't show up.

Update , here is my Payment.php code :

```
<?php
/**
 * Stripe payment method model
 *
 * @category    Inchoo
 * @package     Inchoo_Stripe
 * @author      Ivan Weiler & Stjepan Udovičić
 * @copyright   Inchoo (http://inchoo.net)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

namespace Inchoo\Stripe\Model;

class Payment extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Cc
{
    const CODE = 'inchoo_stripe';

    protected $_code = self::CODE;

    protected $_isGateway                   = true;
    protected $_canCapture                  = true;
    protected $_canCapturePartial           = true;
    protected $_canRefund                   = true;
    protected $_canRefundInvoicePartial     = true;

    protected $_stripeApi = false;

    protected $_countryFactory;

    protected $_minAmount = null;
    protected $_maxAmount = null;
    protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = array('USD');

    protected $_debugReplacePrivateDataKeys = ['number', 'exp_month', 'exp_year', 'cvc'];

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory $customAttributeFactory,
        \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Logger $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleListInterface $moduleList,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory,
        \Stripe\Stripe $stripe,
        array $data = array()
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $registry,
            $extensionFactory,
            $customAttributeFactory,
            $paymentData,
            $scopeConfig,
            $logger,
            $moduleList,
            $localeDate,
            null,
            null,
            $data
        );

        $this->_countryFactory = $countryFactory;

        $this->_stripeApi = $stripe;
        $this->_stripeApi->setApiKey(
            $this->getConfigData('api_key')
        );

        $this->_minAmount = $this->getConfigData('min_order_total');
        $this->_maxAmount = $this->getConfigData('max_order_total');
    }

    /**
     * Payment capturing
     *
     * @param \Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment
     * @param float $amount
     * @return $this
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception
     */
    public function capture(\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment, $amount)
    {
        //throw new \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception(__('Inside Stripe, throwing donuts :]'));

        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
        $order = $payment->getOrder();

        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address $billing */
        $billing = $order->getBillingAddress();

        try {
            $requestData = [
                'amount'        => $amount * 100,
                'currency'      => strtolower($order->getBaseCurrencyCode()),
                'description'   => sprintf('#%s, %s', $order->getIncrementId(), $order->getCustomerEmail()),
                'card'          => [
                    'number'            => $payment->getCcNumber(),
                    'exp_month'         => sprintf('%02d',$payment->getCcExpMonth()),
                    'exp_year'          => $payment->getCcExpYear(),
                    'cvc'               => $payment->getCcCid(),
                    'name'              => $billing->getName(),
                    'address_line1'     => $billing->getStreetLine(1),
                    'address_line2'     => $billing->getStreetLine(2),
                    'address_city'      => $billing->getCity(),
                    'address_zip'       => $billing->getPostcode(),
                    'address_state'     => $billing->getRegion(),
                    'address_country'   => $billing->getCountryId(),
                    // To get full localized country name, use this instead:
                    // 'address_country'   => $this->_countryFactory->create()->loadByCode($billing->getCountryId())->getName(),
                ]
            ];

            $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create($requestData);
            $payment
                ->setTransactionId($charge->id)
                ->setIsTransactionClosed(0);

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->debugData(['request' => $requestData, 'exception' => $e->getMessage()]);
            $this->_logger->error(__('Payment capturing error.'));
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception(__('Payment capturing error.'));
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Payment refund
     *
     * @param \Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment
     * @param float $amount
     * @return $this
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception
     */
    public function refund(\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment, $amount)
    {
        $transactionId = $payment->getParentTransactionId();

        try {
            \Stripe\Charge::retrieve($transactionId)->refund();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->debugData(['transaction_id' => $transactionId, 'exception' => $e->getMessage()]);
            $this->_logger->error(__('Payment refunding error.'));
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception(__('Payment refunding error.'));
        }

        $payment
            ->setTransactionId($transactionId . '-' . \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Transaction::TYPE_REFUND)
            ->setParentTransactionId($transactionId)
            ->setIsTransactionClosed(1)
            ->setShouldCloseParentTransaction(1);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Determine method availability based on quote amount and config data
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface|null $quote
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isAvailable(\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote = null)
    {
        if ($quote && (
            $quote->getBaseGrandTotal() < $this->_minAmount
            || ($this->_maxAmount && $quote->getBaseGrandTotal() > $this->_maxAmount))
        ) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!$this->getConfigData('api_key')) {
            return false;
        }

        return parent::isAvailable($quote);
    }

    /**
     * Availability for currency
     *
     * @param string $currencyCode
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canUseForCurrency($currencyCode)
    {
        if (!in_array($currencyCode, $this->_supportedCurrencyCodes)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}`
```

Comment: How did you add this module to your system? Did you do after installation 'setup:upgrade'? Did you include Stripe classes? Inchoo_Stripe doesn't include Stripe model.

Comment: I did upgrade after installation , but I don't think I've included stripe casses , how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as we figured out, you havent included Stripe lib.
Go there https://stripe.com/docs/libraries and download lib of install via composer.

Then you have to declare using of Stripe lib inside your `Model/Payment.php`. 
Before class declaration need to write `use \Path\To\Stripe.php` and you can use it inside `Model\Payment.php`.

Don't forget to change your code where Stripe class used.

Or you may leave a reply here http://inchoo.net/magento-2/implementing-payment-gateway-magento-2/ right to developers. They may help you.

UPD: Also you should check `/var/log/exception.log` and `/var/log/system.log`.
Actual errors are writing there.

UPD2: Rename /pub/errors/local.xml.sample to /pub/errors/local.xml.

UPD3: Pay atttention on Model\Payment::isAvailable() method and Model\Payment::canUseForCurrency(). Check your parameters according this and make sure you set up right currency and it could be used.

Comment: actually I did installed that library throught composer , by adding this {
  "require": {
    "stripe/stripe-php": "3.*"
  }
}      into my composer.json and update it.

Comment: Update your question with the code of your Model/Payment.php

Comment: And add to description the path where Stripe lib installed.

Comment: How do I find out where the lib is installed , I just installed that throught composer..

Comment: Have a look insode /web/vendor directory. Use file system search.

Comment: And see UPD in my answer.

Comment: Ok so I guess the path is public_html/vendor/stripe/stripe-php/lib/stripe.php , is that right ?

Comment: Yes. And what the namespace inside it? You have to use your Stripe inside Payment.php by Stripe's namespace.

Comment: namespace is Stripe , how do I use it ?

Comment: I guess namespaces is ok. Have a look at the log files. They should help you. I updated my answer again.

Comment: so I don't have to add nothing to my payment.php ?

Comment: It depends on that if you have errors in your log files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40667/discussion-between-white-imp-and-alexcr).

Comment: ok , I've wrote you there !

Comment: I'm getting an issue on the payment , after I enter the details of the card , I get this error message.. please insert a valid credit card expiration date

Comment: you are lucky https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4741 :)

Comment: I found that , did the changes , and now I get "payment capturing error" ..